# Searching all elements before an h2 element in hpricot/nokogiri

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, hpricot, wiktionary

I am attempting to parse a Wiktionary entry to retrieve all english definitions.  I am able to retrive all definitions, the problem is that some definitions are in other languages.  What I would like to do is somehow retrieve only the HTML block with English definitions.  I have found that, in the case that there are other language entries, the header after the english definitions can be retrieved with:

```
header = (doc/"h2")[3]
```

So I would like to only search all the elements before this header element.  I thought that may be possible with `header.preceding_siblings()`, but that does not seem to be working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the visitor pattern with Nokogiri.  This code will remove everything starting from the other language definition's h2:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class Visitor
  def initialize(node)
    @node = node
  end

  def visit(node)
    if @remove || @node == node
      node.remove
      @remove = true
      return
    end
    node.children.each do |child|
      child.accept(self)
    end
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open('http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pony'))
node = doc.search("h2")[2]  #In this case, the Italian h2 is at index 2.  Your page may differ

doc.root.accept(Visitor.new(node))  #Removes all page contents starting from node
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is using **Hpricot**.
It gets the text from the header for the english language (h2) until the next header (h2), or until the footer if there are no further languages:

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

def get_english_definition(url)
  doc = Hpricot(open(url))

  span = doc.at('h2/span[@class="mw-headline"][text()=English]')
  english_header = span && span.parent
  return nil unless english_header

  next_header_or_footer =
    Hpricot::Elements[*english_header.following_siblings].at('h2') ||
    doc.at('[@class="printfooter"]')

  Hpricot::Elements.expand(english_header.next_node,
                           next_header_or_footer.previous_node).to_s
end
```

**Example:**

```
get_english_definition "http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gift"
```

Answer (score 1):

For Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(code)
stop_node = doc.css('h2')[3]
doc.traverse do |node|
  break if node == stop_node
  # else, do whatever, e.g. `puts node.name`
end
```

This will iterate over all the nodes preceding whatever node you designate as `stop_node` in line 2.